# QTextEdit запрет вставка текста с ограничениями

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Доброе время суток!

Есть в приложении поле ввода QTextEdit, если в него вставить текст, к примеру, зеленого цвета с жирным шрифтом, он поддержит этот формат, а надо как раз наоборот, что бы при вставки текста он всегда был в обычным.

Есть ли какой то метод QTextEdit для этого?

Comment: Еще можно QTextEdit заменить на QPlainTextEdit

Comment: Это будет более проблематично

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю речь о вставке из буфера обмена. Если да, то вас интересует свойство 
[`QTextEdit::acceptRichText`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#acceptRichText-prop).

```
textEdit->setAcceptRichText(false);
```